# Executing a proof given a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

The question I am proving:

If $f: X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism show that $A$ is a closed subset of $X$ if and only if $f\left(A\right)$ is a closed subset of $Y$.

The proof that I want to use mimicks the proof of continuity for closed subsets...

where I am saying:

Let

$f: X \to Y$, then $f$ is continous iff for all $V$ closed in $Y$ $f^{-1} \left(V\right)$ is closed in $X$.

Let

$W \in Y$, $f^{-1}\left(Y\right) = X$

Hence

$f^{-1}\left(Y-W\right) = X - f^{-1}\left(W\right)$

I have proved this above secondary statement...I want to know if I can still  use the same structure for the proof for my specific question.

I know that $f$ is a homeomorphism and i know the four conditions:

$f$ must be continous

$f$ must be onto

$f$ must be one to one

$f^{-1}$ must be continous

Any help or guidance would be appreciated i have thought of this problem for a while...It seems similar enough but i may just be seeing what i want to see...

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is a homeomorphism.

Let $A$ be a closed subset of $X$. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f^{-1} : Y \to X$ is continuous and hence $\big(f^{-1}\big)^{-1}(A) = f(A)$ is closed.

Let $f(A)$ be a closed subset of $Y$. Since $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f: X \to Y$ is continuous and $f^{-1} \big( f(A) \big) = A$ is closed in $X$.

So once you prove that secondary statement you mentioned, it works out nicely given the argument above (sans the only if). You want to show: If $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, then if $A$ is closed in $Y$, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $X$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the theorem that continuity is equivalent to "preimages of closed sets are closed" and the facts you list as follows:

Suppose $A$ is closed. then $f(A)=(f^{-1})^{-1}(A)$ is closed because $f^{-1}$ is continous.

On the other hand, if $f(A)$ is closed, then $A=f^{-1}(f(A))$ is closed.